# parse cloud function doesn't return Hebrew characters

Tags: parse-platform

I have a cloud function that send http request to a URL that returns JSON string using Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.
Eventually my cloud function returns this JSON to android client.

When this JSON is received on the client, all the properties that include Hebrew letters are simply removed.

I added this to the headers of Parse.Cloud.httpRequest :

'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'

but it didn't help.

Any idea how it can be fixed?

Thank you

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getReport", function(request, response) {
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://www.url-that-returns-json.com',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
   },  
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
// success
  response.success(httpResponse.text);
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
},function(httpResponse) {
// error
console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I sent a bug report to Parse.

Now this bug seems to be fixed.

Please, try again.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1596679710611808